# How to get all combinations from Sphinx search?

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

I search via Sphinx SQL as

```
SELECT * FROM sphinx.articles WHERE query='something everything;mode=all';
+----------+--------+-------------------------------+
| id       | weight | query                         |
+----------+--------+-------------------------------+
|  2324266 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
|  6997338 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 12002597 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 12543040 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 16314547 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 19094425 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 21398510 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 23020445 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 23040584 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 24059424 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 26009287 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 27476187 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 30488694 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 30698992 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 33191618 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 33900227 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 35671048 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 39324937 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 40373341 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
| 40391221 |      2 | something everything;mode=all |
+----------+--------+-------------------------------+
20 rows in set (0.233 sec)
```

and get the total results by

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Sphinx_total_found';
+--------------------+--------+
| Variable_name      | Value  |
+--------------------+--------+
| Sphinx_total_found | 356179 |
+--------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.004 sec)
```

I wonder if it is possible to get all possible combinations indexed by Sphinx?

For example, to get the number of results for all combinations of two keywords as

```
+-------------------+-------------------------------+
| query                          | total_results    |
+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|  something everything;mode=all | 58844            |
|  word1 word2;mode=all          | 11               |
|  word1 word3;mode=all          | 234              |
|  word2 word3;mode=all          | 663              |
|  word2 word4;mode=all          | 9115             |
+-------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I understand that Sphinx dynamically finds the results by the given keywords in the query, but theoretically, all indexed keywords are known, and we can make the combinations. However, it is too slow if we do the queries individually.

Comment: I think this is about the Sphinx search engine and not the Python-Sphinx documentation generator. The python-sphinx tag should probably be removed.

Comment: Do you mean 'all two word phrases'? Ie each pair of words? http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13229

Comment: @barryhunter my goal is to find the most frequent phrases (two or more words), but I would start with all pairs for simplicity. I look into the bigram_index you linked. I have to re-index but still did not find how to get bigrams as it is an internal feature.

Comment: ok, yes, bigrams should work, yes will have to rebuild the index to enable it. But once enabled provided using 'dict=keywords' should be able to use the 'dumpdict' option on `indextool`